# Broadcom Hybrid Chipset Wifi Works Bluetooth Does Not

Tags: bluetooth, hp

I have a HP Envy Touchsmart 15 and it has a hybrid Broadcom chipset that's both Wifi and Bluetooth. Wifi works excellently however the Bluetooth doesn't work. Ubuntu recognizes that the computer does indeed have Bluetooth and sometimes will detect other Bluetooth devices, but it cannot interact in anyway with them. It can sometimes see, but will not connect, and it is not visible to any other Bluetooth device.

All Bluetooth settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth Manager is often better than the default admin stuff:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/blueman/

Comment: I'm very familiar with Blueman and I used it in my previous laptop and I do agree it works better. However, this issue is with the hardware and not the Bluetooth manager... unfortunately.